# How can I effectively troubleshoot off-by-one bug in C?

Tags: c, off-by-one

I've written a program to reverse a char array and also reverse words within that array. The program almost works as intended but I believe this is an off-by-one error. I've tried messing with the math involving the loop counters but have not been able to figure this one out. What tool or techniques can I use to solve this type of problem? I've tried printf statements and also using gdb and placing a watch on the counter variables.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void reverse_arr(char *arr, size_t len);
void print_chars(char *arr, size_t len);
void reverse_words(char *arr, size_t len);
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char phrase[] = {'p','e','r','f','e','c','t',' ',
                    'm','a','k','e','s',' ','p','r',
                    'a','c','t','i','c','e'};

        size_t i;

    reverse_arr(phrase, sizeof(phrase));
    reverse_words(phrase,sizeof(phrase));
    print_chars(phrase, sizeof(phrase));

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

void reverse_arr(char *arr, size_t len)
{
    size_t front, tail;
    tail = len-1;
    char tmp;
    for(front = 0; front < len/2; front++, tail--)
    {
        tmp = arr[front];
        arr[front] = arr[tail];
        arr[tail] = tmp;
    }

    return;
}

// 1. Search for a space
// 2. When space is found, that space is the place to stop and indicates all between the start and it are a word
// 3. Now call reverse_arr on the word and calculate the length of the word by subtracting tail - start
// 
void reverse_words(char *arr, size_t len)
{
    size_t tail, start;
    for(tail = start = 0; tail < len; tail++)
    {
        if(arr[tail] == ' ' || tail == len-1)
        {
            reverse_arr(&arr[start], tail - start);
            start = tail+1;
        }
    }
}

void print_chars(char *arr, size_t len)
{
    size_t i;
    for(i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        putchar(arr[i]);
    }
    putchar('\n');

    return;
}
```

This code returns `practice makes erfectp`. Clearly, this is an off-by-one bug but I've spent some time on this and suffered similar bugs in C in other programs.

Comment: Have you narrowed it down to one function call in `main`, at least? (`reverse_arr` or `reverse_words`) That would be the first step, since they’re completely separate and you can print/use the debugger to examine `phrase` between them.

Comment: The names of your functions suggest that your output should be `ecitcarp sekam tcefrep`. Is that indeed what you are trying to get?

Comment: @goodvibration: `reverse_words` reverses each word for an intended output of “practice makes perfect”

Comment: And `reverse_arr`?

Comment: You flush them out by testing with *small* test cases, the kind where you can easily trace the program execution with the debugger.  You won't need anything larger than 4 characters to cover all conditions.  Start with an empty array, you fix that bug first and consider that a string might be a better choice.  Progress.

Comment: @HansPassant Would you mind expanding on this and using some example code in an answer? The current answer explains the bug but the question actually was in a generic sense, how to flush stuff like this out and I think you have a shot at answering it. Thanks for considering.

Answer (score 1):

The bug is in `reverse_words`.  Sometimes `tail` indexes the character *after* the last character of the word, and sometimes `tail` indexes the last character of the word itself.

The call to `reverse_array` from `reverse_words` is:

```
reverse_arr(&arr[start], tail - start);
```

This works if `start` indexes the first character of the word, and if there are `tail - start` characters in the word.  So `tail` must index the character *after* the last character of the word.

The condition `arr[tail] == ' '` is consistent with this, but end condition is not:  (1) the loop exits too soon, and (2) the test `tail == len-1` is also off by one.

This can be fixed by iterating one more time, and checking the end condition *before* trying to access `arr[tail]` (to avoid indexing past the end):

```
void reverse_words(char *arr, size_t len)
{
    size_t tail, start;
    for (tail = start = 0; tail <= len; tail++)
    {
        if (tail == len || arr[tail] == ' ')
        {
            reverse_arr(&arr[start], tail - start);
            start = tail+1;
        }
    }
}
```

Note that the loop exit condition is now `<=` rather then `<`, the in-loop end test has shifted by one, and the order of the checks within the loop is reversed.

Comment: So I got a question. In the statement `if (tail == len || arr[tail] == ' ')` does C actually guarantee to evaluate `tail == len` *before* the `arr[tail]`? I'm trying to find this in the C standard because I've wondered this for a while. Also, what means of debugging did you use to figure this out?

Comment: @the_endian Yes, it's called short-circuiting.  For `||`, the second operand is only evaluated if the first is false.  And for `&&`, the second operand is only evaluated if the first is true.  You can test it by putting a function call into the second operand, and having that function print something when called.  Regarding debugging, I just looked at the loop and noticed the problems by inspection.